# SafeArray из SafeArray в коде VBA: его перевод на С++

Tags: c++, vba, com

Привет!

есть один маленький кусочек кода из VBA — передача параметра в функцию.
В коде VBA макроса параметр = это вот такой монстр:

```
FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 2), Array(5, 2)),
```

вопрос — в виде чего это представится на С++ ?
Вроде как я должен создать safearray оf safearray of variants of VT_INT типа?
при помощи SafeArrayCreate — так что ли?
Или SafeArrayCreateVectorEx правильнее заюзать?

не подскажите в виде хотя бы псевдо-кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Create a 5x2 safearray of integer arrays with VT_I4 fields...
comstl::variant fieldInfo;
fieldInfo.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT;
{
    SAFEARRAYBOUND sab[2];
    sab[0].lLbound = 1; sab[0].cElements = 5; // i
    sab[1].lLbound = 1; sab[1].cElements = 2;  // j
    fieldInfo.parray = SafeArrayCreate(VT_VARIANT, 2, sab);
}

// Fill safearray with values like:
/*
   FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 2), Array(5, 2))
 */
// first of all fill the first column with data...
for(int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    VARIANT tmp;
    tmp.vt = VT_I4;
    tmp.lVal = i;
    // Add to safearray...
    long indices[] = {i,1};
    SafeArrayPutElement(fieldInfo.parray, indices, (void *)&tmp);
}
// ...after that - fill the second column.
for(int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    VARIANT tmp;
    tmp.vt = VT_I4;
    tmp.lVal = 2;
    // Add to safearray...
    long indices[] = {i,2};
    SafeArrayPutElement(fieldInfo.parray, indices, (void *)&tmp);
}
```

вот такой пепелац заставил мой код работать.
Чтож - надеюсь, кому-нить это решение поможет.